# How to get dynamic variable in string in r?

Tags: r

How can I get the variable name of a function to act dynamically within a string?

Below is an extract of what I am trying to achieve: a function that produces a list depending on the varName. But I cannot get the varName to act dynamically within the string `sqldf(...)`. I assume this problem is not specific to the package `sqldf`.

```
createExcelSheetData<-function(varName){
  sqldf("
         SELECT Name 
         FROM dataTable
         WHERE Choice=varName
       ")
}
table1<-createExcelSheetData(1)
table2<-createExcelSheetData(2)
table3<-createExcelSheetData(3)
```

What the above gives me is the choice fixed with the text `varName`.

UPDATE: To have the variable within the text, not just at the end.

```
createExcelSheetData<-function(varName){
  sqldf("
         SELECT Name 
         FROM dataTable
         WHERE Choice=varName
         ORDER BY Name
       ")
}
table1<-createExcelSheetData(1)
table2<-createExcelSheetData(2)
table3<-createExcelSheetData(3)
```

Comment: Use `paste`: `sqldf(paste("SELECT Name FROM dataTable WHERE Choice=",varName))`.

Comment: @nicola Thanks for the answer. It works. Will I need two uses of paste if the text is not just at the end? Or is there a more elegant solution? See update for what I mean?

Comment: See `?paste`. You have to build the string of the query. In the case of the update, try `paste("SELECT Name FROM dataTable WHERE Choice=",varName,"ORDER BY Name")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fn$` is discussed in Example 6 on the [sqldf home page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf).  Here is a self contained minimial reproducible example using the `iris` data frame that comes with R: (In the future please ensure all code is minimal and reproducible and in particular includes all inputs).

```
library(sqldf)

# retrieve records for specified Species and Petal.Length above minPetalLength
f <- function(Species, minPetalLength) {
           fn$sqldf("SELECT * 
                     FROM iris 
                     WHERE Species = '$Species' and [Petal.Length] > $minPetalLength")
}

f("virginica", 6)
```

giving:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
2          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
3          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
4          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
5          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
6          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
7          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica
8          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
9          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
```

Comment: Many thanks. I see from your answer that the problem is indeed `sqldf` dependent. What if I wanted a function that does a similar replacement within another function (such as `write.xlsx`)?

Comment: No. It is not sqldf dependent.  fn is not even part of sqldf.  It is part of gsubfn which sqldf automatically pulls in. fn works with nearly any function.    Try ?fn for more info.  I only used sqldf because you did.